# CPP: Capturing returned reference by value (i.e; in an lvalue of the referred type)

Tags: c++

I tried this code to test how the returned reference gets propagated if captured by value:

```
int& give_rint()
{ 
    std::unique_ptr<int> x(new int(32)); 
    return *x; 
}

int main()
{
    int b = give_rint();
    std::cout << b << std::endl; // prints 0
    return 0;
}
```

I expected this to print 32, assuming that b would copy the value referred to by the returned type (which I again "assumed" would be alive for the line `int b = give_rint();`

While asking for an understanding of the series of events happening at above line. My question is also, can I somehow emulate the same behavior within a function, say something like(presented below doesn't work the same):

```
int main()
{
    int b;
    {
        std::unique_ptr<int> x(new int(32));
        int& c = *x;
        b = c; 
    }
    std::cout << b << std::endl; // prints 32;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I expected this to print 32

When the function returns, unique pointer is destroyed, and the allocated memory is deallocated. The returned reference is always invalid.

When you indirect through the invalid reference by using it to initialise `b`, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> can I somehow emulate the same behavior within a function

Producing an invalid reference is challenging within a single function, but producing an invalid pointer is easy, and equally undefined. However, since the behaviour is undefined, there are no guarantees that it would be **same** undefined behaviour.

---

This is what clang says when the program is compiled:

> warning: reference to stack memory associated with local variable 'x' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
>
> ```
> return *x; 
>         ^
> ```

And this is what happens at runtime:

> ```
> ==1==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free
> ```